# .Net Core Entity Framework .Include Eager load does not load entity

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, eager-loading

My first question - be kind :-).

In the code below, I am attempting to reference an "Include(d)" entity (Schedules) to obtain its Name property. In EF 6, both "schedule" and "schedule_2" return the correct value of Name. In EF Core, "schedule" returns NULL and "schedule_2" returns the correct value of Name.

I do not understand why I should have to load the "schedules" List. Shouldn't the .Include force an Eager Load of the Schedules for each Election such that each Election Schedule's Name property would be available for the "schedule" assignment?

```
// Relevant Model entities in database
//         DbSet<Election> Elections { get; set; }
//
// The following are the related classes defined in the database context...
public class Election
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
}
public class Schedule
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CfsElectionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required] // sets cascade delete
    [ForeignKey("CFSElectionID")]
    public virtual Election Election { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var db = new FfmsDbContext();
        var elections = db.Elections
            .Include(i => i.Schedules)
            .ToList();

        //The following returns NULL?
        var schedule = elections.First().Schedules?.First().Name ?? "NULL";

        var schedules = db.Schedules
            .ToList();

        //The following returns the correct Name property?
        var schedule_2 = elections.First().Schedules?.First().Name ?? "NULL";

        Console.WriteLine($@"sched: {schedule}");
        Console.WriteLine($@"schedules.First().Name: {schedules.First().Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($@"sched2: {schedule_2}");

        Console.WriteLine("Done...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

/*
  Output...
    sched: NULL
    schedules.First().Name: Candidates
    sched2: Candidates
    Done...
*/
```

Comment: have you tried configure  `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` ? in DBContext ?

Comment: @zey -- Thanks for the idea.  I've now tried all possible uses of LazyLoadingEnabled. In my reading though, I don't see how this parameter helps though.  What I want is Eager loading (always load the related entity on first access).

Answer (score 9):

Turns out that my problem ended up being in the References of the Class.

I had accidentally chosen `System.Data.Entity` as the offered choice for .Include.

The correct reference should have been `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Once I adjusted the reference, the `.Include` worked as desired.

Comment: Eugh also did this! Thanks so much for posting - I could have wasted a lot (more) time  looking for this!

Comment: I can't believe this doesn't throw an error somewhere, like "Invalid use of Include on System.Data.Entity" I wasted a lot of time before I found this!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasted a few hours in this trap when upgrading a project from .NET Framework 4.8 with EF6 to .NET 6 with EF Core 6. Interestingly, it still works with the In-Memory provider (maybe because it always does eager loading), but not with a real SQL Server database.

Comment: god bless you. I spent 2 days trying to figure out why the same db context behaves differently for 2 different classes. So stupid :)